# How to transform rows of other columns to columns on the basis of unique values of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a df in the following structure,

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 | column7
   A    |    B    |    C    |    10   |    78   |   12    |  202001
   A    |    B    |    D    |    21   |    64   |   87    |  202001
   A    |    B    |    E    |    21   |    64   |   87    |  202001
   X    |    K    |    C    |    54   |    23   |   23    |  202001
   X    |    K    |    D    |    21   |    55   |   87    |  202001
   X    |    K    |    E    |    21   |    43   |   22    |  202001
   A    |    B    |    C    |    10   |    78   |   12    |  202002
   A    |    B    |    D    |    23   |    64   |   87    |  202002
   A    |    B    |    E    |    21   |    11   |   34    |  202002
   Z    |    K    |    C    |    10   |    78   |   12    |  202002
   Z    |    K    |    D    |    21   |    13   |   56    |  202002
   Z    |    K    |    E    |    12   |    77   |   34    |  202002
```

relation between column1 to column2 - one to many

relation between column2 to column1 - one to many

Expected Output:

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4_202001 | column5_202001 | column6_202001 | column4_202002 | column5_202002 | column6_202002 |
   A    |    B    |    C    |      10        |       78       |       12       |      10        |      78        |      12        |
   A    |    B    |    D    |      21        |       64       |       87       |      23        |      64        |      87        |
   A    |    B    |    E    |      21        |       64       |       87       |      21        |      11        |      34        |   
   X    |    K    |    C    |      54        |       23       |       23       |       0        |       0        |       0        |   
   X    |    K    |    D    |      21        |       55       |       87       |       0        |       0        |       0        |   
   X    |    K    |    E    |      21        |       43       |       22       |       0        |       0        |       0        |    
   Z    |    K    |    C    |       0        |        0       |        0       |      10        |      78        |      12        |    
   Z    |    K    |    D    |       0        |        0       |        0       |      21        |      13        |      56        |   
   Z    |    K    |    E    |       0        |        0       |        0       |      12        |      77        |      34        |
```

Also, while transforming, for every column7 can I create an empty column right beside column6_yyyymm?

Final Output,

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4_202001 | column5_202001 | column6_202001 |   empty_202001 | column4_202002 | column5_202002 | column6_202002 | empty_202002 ....
   A    |    B    |    C    |      10        |       78       |       12       |                |      10        |      78        |      12        |
   A    |    B    |    D    |      21        |       64       |       87       |                |      23        |      64        |      87        |
   A    |    B    |    E    |      21        |       64       |       87       |                |      21        |      11        |      34        |   
   X    |    K    |    C    |      54        |       23       |       23       |                |      0         |       0        |       0        |   
   X    |    K    |    D    |      21        |       55       |       87       |                |      0         |       0        |       0        |   
   X    |    K    |    E    |      21        |       43       |       22       |                |      0         |       0        |       0        |    
   Z    |    K    |    C    |       0        |        0       |        0       |                |      10        |      78        |      12        |    
   Z    |    K    |    D    |       0        |        0       |        0       |                |      21        |      13        |      56        |   
   Z    |    K    |    E    |       0        |        0       |        0       |                |      12        |      77        |      34        |
```

How can I achieve Final Output using a python function and/or pandas library? If there is anything unclear please let me know.

UPDATE:

For all empty_yyyymm columns I want to implement the following function,

```
        def get_final(row):
        if row['column2'].isin(['H', 'S', 'Z']):
            return 0
        elif row['column4_yyyymm'] + row['column5_yyyymm'] - row['column6_yyyymm'] < 0 and not row['column2'].isin(['H', 'S', 'Z']):
            return 0
        else:
            return row['column4_yyyymm'] + row['column5_yyyymm'] - row['column6_yyyymm']
```

How can achieve this too?

Note: yyyymm is generic way of referring column7. It is not actually a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create empty column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and sorting datetimes in second level by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = (df.assign(empty = np.nan)
        .set_index(['column1','column2','column3','column7'])
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=1))
```

Then set values missing to all `empty` columns, flatten `MultiIndex in columns` by `map` and last convert `index` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df['empty'] = np.nan
#if need fill by empty string
#df['empty'] = ''
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  column1 column2 column3  column4_202001  column5_202001  column6_202001  \
0       A       B       C              10              78              12   
1       A       B       D              21              64              87   
2       A       B       E              21              64              87   
3       X       K       C              54              23              23   
4       X       K       D              21              55              87   
5       X       K       E              21              43              22   
6       Z       K       C               0               0               0   
7       Z       K       D               0               0               0   
8       Z       K       E               0               0               0   

   empty_202001  column4_202002  column5_202002  column6_202002  empty_202002  
0           NaN              10              78              12           NaN  
1           NaN              23              64              87           NaN  
2           NaN              21              11              34           NaN  
3           NaN               0               0               0           NaN  
4           NaN               0               0               0           NaN  
5           NaN               0               0               0           NaN  
6           NaN              10              78              12           NaN  
7           NaN              21              13              56           NaN  
8           NaN              12              77              34           NaN
```

EDIT: First count new column `empty` by conditions and then apply solution above without set `NaN` like:

```
m1 = df['column2'].isin(['H', 'S', 'Z'])

s = df['column4'] + df['column5'] - df['column6']
m2 = (s < 0) & ~m1

out = np.where(m1 | m2, 0, s)
df = (df.assign(empty = out)
        .set_index(['column1','column2','column3','column7'])
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=1))

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
  column1 column2 column3  column4_202001  column5_202001  column6_202001  \
0       A       B       C              10              78              12   
1       A       B       D              21              64              87   
2       A       B       E              21              64              87   
3       X       K       C              54              23              23   
4       X       K       D              21              55              87   
5       X       K       E              21              43              22   
6       Z       K       C               0               0               0   
7       Z       K       D               0               0               0   
8       Z       K       E               0               0               0   

   empty_202001  column4_202002  column5_202002  column6_202002  empty_202002  
0            76              10              78              12            76  
1             0              23              64              87             0  
2             0              21              11              34             0  
3            54               0               0               0             0  
4             0               0               0               0             0  
5            42               0               0               0             0  
6             0              10              78              12            76  
7             0              21              13              56             0  
8             0              12              77              34            55
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have added one more small update to the question. What do you think would be the best way to use the function for a given empty_yyyymm column? Each empty_yyyymm column would refer to its respective column4_yyyymm, column5_yyyymm, column6_yyyymm. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @royalewithcheese - I see it, I need some time. But possible for first look

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Function should be changed? E.g for test `str(row['column2']) in ['H', 'S', 'Z']` use `df['column2'].isin(['H', 'S', 'Z'])` ?

Comment: Sure, as long as it checks column2 has one of the values..

Comment: Also, hope you know in function by writing column4_yyyymm, column5_yyyymm, and column6_yyyymm, here yyyymm is generic based on the values of column7. That is, for 202001 I want a column with that function implemented, for 202002 I want another column with that function implemented and so on..
That is why I was thinking if there is a way of implementing the function while transforming..

Comment: @royalewithcheese - added solution for count values before original solution, for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column7'])
   .rename_axis(['idx'], axis=1)
   .unstack('column7')
   .reset_index().fillna(0))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: '_'.join([str(i) for i in x]) if (x[1])!='' else x[0])
```

---

|  | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4_202001 | column4_202002 | column5_202001 | column5_202002 | column6_202001 | column6_202002 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | B | C | 10.0 | 10.0 | 78.0 | 78.0 | 12.0 | 12.0 |
| 1 | A | B | D | 21.0 | 23.0 | 64.0 | 64.0 | 87.0 | 87.0 |
| 2 | A | B | E | 21.0 | 21.0 | 64.0 | 11.0 | 87.0 | 34.0 |
| 3 | X | K | C | 54.0 | 0.0 | 23.0 | 0.0 | 23.0 | 0.0 |
| 4 | X | K | D | 21.0 | 0.0 | 55.0 | 0.0 | 87.0 | 0.0 |
| 5 | X | K | E | 21.0 | 0.0 | 43.0 | 0.0 | 22.0 | 0.0 |
| 6 | Z | K | C | 0.0 | 10.0 | 0.0 | 78.0 | 0.0 | 12.0 |
| 7 | Z | K | D | 0.0 | 21.0 | 0.0 | 13.0 | 0.0 | 56.0 |
| 8 | Z | K | E | 0.0 | 12.0 | 0.0 | 77.0 | 0.0 | 34.0 |

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because you forgot to add the empty columns as it was one of criteria's for the question. I have updated my question, please have a look.